# RSpec expect to receive method with array but order does not matter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Lets say I have method `#sum` which takes an array and calculates sum of all elements. I'm stubbing it:

```
  before do
    expect(calculation_service).to receive(:sum?).with([1, 2, 3]) { 6 }
  end
```

unfortunately my test suit passes array in random order. Because of that error is raised:

```
 Failure/Error: subject { do_crazy_stuff! }
   #<InstanceDouble() (CalculationService)> received :sum? with unexpected arguments
     expected: ([1, 2, 3])
          got: ([3, 2, 1])
```

Is it possible to stub method call ignoring order of an array elements? `array_including(1, 2, 3)` does not ensure about array size, so it probably is not the best solution here

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can pass any RSpec matcher to `with`, and `contain_exactly(1, 2, 3)` does exactly what you want, so you can pass that to with:

```
expect(calculation_service).to receive(:sum?).with(contain_exactly(1, 2, 3)) { 6 }
```

However, "with contain exactly 1, 2, 3" doesn't read very well (and the failure message will be similarly grammatically awkward), so RSpec 3 provides aliases that solve both problems.  In this case, you can use `a_collection_containing_exactly`:

```
expect(calculation_service).to receive(:sum?).with(
  a_collection_containing_exactly(1, 2, 3)
) { 6 }
```

Comment: Just remember to spread the array if you're passing it to the contain_exactly, like `expect(calculation_service).to receive(:sum?).with(contain_exactly(*my_array))`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the method [`match_array`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array). This way, you don't need to first split the elements of the array; instead, you can just use the whole array to match.

So you can use:

```
expect(calculation_service).to receive(:sum?).with(match_array([1, 2, 3])) { 6 }
```